# Different solutions of homogenous system

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I'm solving a homogenous system.

One solution:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & -2 & 2 & -1\\
1 & 2 & -1 & 3 & -2\\
2 & 4 & -7 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & -2 & 2 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & -3 & -3 & \color{red}{\fbox{$-1$}}
\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{cases}
x=-2a-4b+3c\\
y=a\\
z=-b+c\\
s=b\\
t=c
\end{cases}\rightarrow a\begin{pmatrix}-2\\
1\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}-4\\
0\\
-1\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}+c\begin{pmatrix}3\\
0\\
1\\
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Another solution: what if I also “eliminate” the last row in the second matrix, i.e. (0,0,-3,-3,1)?
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & -2 & 2 & -1\\
1 & 2 & -1 & 3 & -2\\
2 & 4 & -7 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & -2 & 2 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & -3 & -3 & \color{red}{\fbox{$-1$}}
\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & -2 & 2 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{\fbox{$-4$}}
\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{cases}
x=-2a-4b\\
y=a\\
z=-b\\
s=b\\
t=0
\end{cases}\rightarrow a\begin{pmatrix}-2\\
1\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}-4\\
0\\
-1\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So, additional elimination turned a free variable t into pivot! Something is wrong here. It looks like that I “reduced” the solution space: it's the same solution as above but with $c=0$.

Questions:

1. What had happened?
2. When should I stop elimination in order not to lose part of the
   answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an arithmetic error in the second matrix:  the $(3, 5)$ entry ought to be $3$ (not $-1$ as you have written).

Your first solution is correct, anyway.

By the way, you can discover the pivots (and number of free variables, as well) by putting the matrix into **row echelon form.**  But, in order to actually parametrize the solution space, you need to go further to **reduced row echelon form** (with zeroes *above* the pivot, as well).  That's when you can stop the elimination procedure.

Comment: Oh, yes. Then, the last row turns into zero row, and the solution remains as in the 1st case.

Comment: I wonder should I edit my question replacing -1 with 3 or leave as it was? In case I edit, there will be no question to ask :)

Comment: You might as well leave it so that the question/answer pair makes sense.  I highlighted the numbers in $\color{red}{\fbox{red}}$.